# MySQL 5.7 group replication disables access over TCP/IP

Tags: mysql, replication, high-availability, mysql-5.7

I'am testing new group-replication feature on MySQL 5.7 with multi-master replication on a Windows 2012 R2 system. I'm using for testing a single server and install to MySQL instance onm  TCP-Ports 3306 and 3306 using diffent data-dirs and tcp-ports, etc.

All works fine, even setting up group replication. But when i use `start replication`, i can't connect per TCP/IP (`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`) anymore only by socket (`mysql -h localhost -u root -p`).

Before starting group replication on second master:

```
>mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p -e "status; show processlist; SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members"
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)

Connection id:          16
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.17-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3307
Uptime:                 2 min 52 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 43  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 127  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 120  Queries per second avg: 0.250
--------------

+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| 16 | root | localhost:49333 | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| group_replication_applier | c6dc60ef-f8db-11e6-b78f-005056aae5b3 | RS-6-48     |        3307 | OFFLINE      |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

starting group replication with `mysql -P 3307 -u root -p -e "START GROUP_REPLICATION"`

After that trying to connect per tcp/ip is stucked endless. The TCP-Port is open and you can connect, but nothing more. The server is only reachable by `localhost`:

```
>mysql -h localhost -P 3307 -u root -p -e "status; show processlist; SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members"
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Win64 (x86_64)

Connection id:          39
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.17-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log MySQL Enterprise Server - Advanced Edition (Commercial)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3307
Uptime:                 6 min 33 sec

Threads: 4  Questions: 87  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 137  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 130  Queries per second avg: 0.221
--------------

+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| Id | User        | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State                                                  | Info             |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| 28 | system user |                 | NULL | Connect |   30 | System lock                                            | NULL             |
| 31 | system user |                 | NULL | Connect |   30 | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates | NULL             |
| 39 | root        | localhost:49358 | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting                                               | show processlist |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| group_replication_applier | 76c585ef-f8df-11e6-80f7-005056aae5b3 | RS-6-48     |        3306 | ONLINE       |
| group_replication_applier | c6dc60ef-f8db-11e6-b78f-005056aae5b3 | RS-6-48     |        3307 | ONLINE       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

If a stop the replication again. Server is reachable under `127.0.0.1` again.

Any hints solving this problem? Thanks.

Appendix 1: excerpt from MySQL error log when starting group replication:

```
2017-02-23T06:59:15.291541Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group communication SSL configuration: group_replication_ssl_mode: "DISABLED"'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.291541Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.291541Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Added automatically IP ranges 10.32.6.48/8,127.0.0.1/8 to the whitelist'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.291541Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] SSL was not enabled'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.291541Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Initialized group communication with configuration: group_replication_group_name: "ced7cae9-6e09-455e-9fe0-a55627f7291d"; group_replication_local_address: "10.32.6.48:3307"; group_replication_group_seeds: "10.32.6.48:3306,10.32.6.48:3307"; group_replication_bootstrap_group: false; group_replication_poll_spin_loops: 0; group_replication_compression_threshold: 1000000; group_replication_ip_whitelist: "AUTOMATIC"'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.291541Z 14 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group Replication applier module successfully initialized!'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 17 [Note] Slave SQL thread for channel 'group_replication_applier' initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\railsys-enterprise-relay-bin-group_replication_applier.000008' position: 4
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'auto_increment_increment is set to 7'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 12 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'auto_increment_offset is set to 2'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'state 4257 action xa_init'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Successfully bound to 0.0.0.0:3307 (socket=2688).'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Successfully set listen backlog to 32 (socket=2688)!'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Successfully unblocked socket (socket=2688)!'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3307'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.307218Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Ready to accept incoming connections on 0.0.0.0:3307 (socket=2688)!'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.322881Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3307 fd 2996'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.322881Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3307'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.338478Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3307 fd 2696'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.338478Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3307'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.354138Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3307 fd 2740'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.354138Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3307'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.369687Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3307 fd 3000'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.369687Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3307'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.385311Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3307 fd 2676'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.385311Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3307'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.400933Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3307 fd 3004'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.400933Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 10.32.6.48 3306'
2017-02-23T06:59:15.416653Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'client connected to 10.32.6.48 3306 fd 2752'
2017-02-23T06:59:16.838441Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'state 4257 action xa_snapshot'
2017-02-23T06:59:16.838441Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'new state x_recover'
2017-02-23T06:59:16.838441Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'state 4277 action xa_complete'
2017-02-23T06:59:16.838441Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'new state x_run'
2017-02-23T06:59:21.213450Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: 'This member has more executed transactions than those present in the group. Local transactions: 76c585ef-f8df-11e6-80f7-005056aae5b3:1,
c6dc60ef-f8db-11e6-b78f-005056aae5b3:1,
ced7cae9-6e09-455e-9fe0-a55627f7291d:1-1501 > Group transactions: 76c585ef-f8df-11e6-80f7-005056aae5b3:1,
ced7cae9-6e09-455e-9fe0-a55627f7291d:1-1502'
2017-02-23T06:59:21.213450Z 0 [Warning] Plugin group_replication reported: 'The member contains transactions not present in the group. It is only allowed to join due to group_replication_allow_local_disjoint_gtids_join option'
2017-02-23T06:59:21.213450Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Starting group replication recovery with view_id 14877553113022027:16'
2017-02-23T06:59:21.213450Z 20 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Establishing group recovery connection with a possible donor. Attempt 1/10'
2017-02-23T06:59:27.291607Z 20 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='RS-6-48', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2017-02-23T06:59:27.322957Z 20 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Establishing connection to a group replication recovery donor 76c585ef-f8df-11e6-80f7-005056aae5b3 at RS-6-48 port: 3306.'
2017-02-23T06:59:27.322957Z 21 [Warning] Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please consider using the USER and PASSWORD connection options for START SLAVE; see the 'START SLAVE Syntax' in the MySQL Manual for more information.
2017-02-23T06:59:27.322957Z 22 [Note] Slave SQL thread for channel 'group_replication_recovery' initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\railsys-enterprise-relay-bin-group_replication_recovery.000001' position: 4
2017-02-23T06:59:27.322957Z 21 [Note] Slave I/O thread for channel 'group_replication_recovery': connected to master 'replication@RS-6-48:3306',replication started in log 'FIRST' at position 4
2017-02-23T06:59:27.354089Z 20 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Terminating existing group replication donor connection and purging the corresponding logs.'
2017-02-23T06:59:27.354089Z 21 [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event for channel 'group_replication_recovery'
2017-02-23T06:59:27.354089Z 21 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting for channel 'group_replication_recovery', read up to log 'railsys-enterprise-bin.000002', position 607517
2017-02-23T06:59:27.354089Z 20 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='RS-6-48', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2017-02-23T06:59:27.385522Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'This server was declared online within the replication group'
```

Appendix 2:
Server A my.ini:

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
loose-group_replication_local_address="10.32.6.48:3306"
loose-group_replication_group_seeds="10.32.6.48:3306,10.32.6.48:3307"
```

Server B my.ini

```
[mysqld]
port=3307
loose-group_replication_local_address="10.32.6.48:3307"
loose-group_replication_group_seeds="10.32.6.48:3306,10.32.6.48:3307"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL error log should have some clues. Can you show the log snippet from just after you issue `START GROUP_REPLICATION`?

*Edit*: after seeing the MySQL error log snippet...

It looks like you're perhaps using the same port for the mysql protocol and the GCS (group communication system)?

You have to use different ports. For example, in your config:

```
[mysqld]
port=3307
group_replication_local_address = '10.32.6.48:6606'
group_replication_group_seeds = '10.32.6.49:6606,10.32.6.50:6606'
```

Comment: Thanks, i added **appendix 1** with the error log to my questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I change the group_replication to `loose-group_replication_local_address="10.32.6.48:6606"` and 
`loose-group_replication_group_seeds="10.32.6.48:6606,10.32.6.48:6607"`